# Overlap area of two disks with known radii and known distance between the centers

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area

How do you find the red-filled area of this picture ? (Sorry for my drawing skill.)

[image]

- The radius of larger circle is R = 4
- The radius of smaller circle is r = 3
- The distance between both center (Green Line) is 0.4*R = 1.6

That is all initial condition the question give. I have no idea to find blue-filled angle in this picture.

[image]

I get this question long time ago that I can't remember when or how. I doubt if this question give enough initial condition or not. The initial condition might not enough to give specific blue-filled angle and specific red-filled area value. Sorry if this question isn't complete.

Comment: Subtract the area of the smallest "lune" ( = crescent shape) as given by the formula to be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lune_(geometry)) to the area of the smallest disc.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace your former title "Two different-radius Circle intersect area with few initial conditions" by the present one in order to describe in a closer way what the issue is about.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for giving better topic name. About the link, what is c in the formula ?

Comment: $c$ is the distance between the centers.

Comment: Remark: The inverse secant function which is needed for applying the formula I gave upwards can be expressed using $\arcsin$ or $\arctan$ functions (see formulas 14 and 15 [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseSecant.html))

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the formula. But is it possible to calculate without using formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE. Here is my attempt:

[image]

Suppose the length of common chord is $AB=l$, the angle opposite to it is $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the length of segment  between centers and common chord is $O_1H=a$ and $O_2H=b$ in circles $R=4$ and $r=3$ respectively.  we have:

$(\frac l 2)^2+ a^2=4^2$

$(\frac l 2)^2+ b^2=3^2$

Subtracting these relations we get:

$(a-b)(a+b)=16-9=7$

It is clear in your figure that we have:

$a-b=1.6 \Rightarrow a+b=\frac 7{1.6}$

Which gives :

$a=2.9875$, $b=1.3875$

$(\frac l 2)^2=3^2-1.3875^2$

which gives $\frac l 2=2.66\rightarrow l\approx 5,32$

$\Rightarrow  \sin \frac {\alpha}2\approx \frac {2.66}4\approx 0.665 \Rightarrow \frac{\alpha} 2 \approx 41.7^o\rightarrow \alpha\approx 83.36^o $

The ares S you are looking for is:

$S=S_1+S_2$

Where:

$S_1$ is the portion related to big circle and is between arc AB of big circle and lines AB, so we have:

$S_1=S_{R=4}-S_{\triangle AO_1B}$

$S_2$ is the portion related to little circle and is between left side of arc AB of little circle and line AB, so we have:

$S_2=S_{r=3}+S_{\triangle AO_2B}$

Now we use this formula:

$S=\frac {\pi R^2\times \alpha^o}{360}$

Plugging values we get:

$S_{R=4}\approx 11.634$

$S_1=S_{R=4}-S_{\triangle AO_1B}$

$S_{AO_1B}=\frac l 2\times O_1H=2.66\times 2.988=7.95$

$\Rightarrow S_1=11.634-7.95=3.684$

Similarly for circle $r=3$ we get:

$\beta\approx 124.9^o$

$S_{r=3; right side}\approx 9.8$

$S_{r=3; left side}\approx 18.455$

$S_2=S_{left side}+S_{\triangle AO_2B}$

$S_{AO_2B}=\frac l 2 \times O_2H=2.66\times 1.388\approx 3.692$

$S_2=18.455+3.692=22.1462$

Finally required are is :

$S=S_1+S_2=3.684+22.1462\approx 25.83$

it is entire ares of little circle except:

$3^2\times 3.14-28,83=2.4298$

Comment: I try to understand everything after $S=\frac{\pi R^2\alpha^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}}$ but I don't understand what you mean.
You say $S=\frac{\pi R^2\alpha^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}}$ and then $S_{R=4} \approx 11.634$. You mean $S_{R=4} = S = \frac{\pi R^2\alpha^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}} \approx 11.634$, right ? Since $\alpha^{\circ}$ and R is for only the larger circle.
Then you say $S = S_1 + S_2 \approx 25.83$, so what the S is ?

Comment: @signinuesdto, I added more data for clarification.

Comment: Thank you. It will be better to say $S_{x,a^{\circ}} = \frac{\pi x^2a^{\circ}}{360^{\circ}}$ where x is radius and $a^{\circ}$ is angle. So, it will not cause confusion to the reader.

Comment: You'r welcome. I just wrote the formula in it's standard form.